# Change execution of java program while debugging

Tags: java, eclipse

In Visual Studio, while debugging, you can change execution flow of program by returning up via stack. I mean, after you passed some expression and debugger is highlighting next line, you can return up and execute that expression again.

Is this possible while debugging Java programs?

Comment: You can do it with breakpoints and Debug Mode with NetBeans, I'm not sure about eclipse though.

Comment: No, I meant you can make "step back" and return where you just passed.

Answer (score 1):

When you change a method after evaluating that section in the debugger a prompt appears:

> Obsolete Methods on the Stack
>
> Reason: The virtual machine was unable to remove all stack frames
>   running  old code from the call stack. The virtual machine is not
>   supplying the debugger with valid data for those frames. Stepping into
>   these obsolete frames may be hazardous to the target virtual machine.

Then there are three buttons: Continue, Terminate and Restart.

If you press Restart the code will reevaluate and return you to either a new break-point (if you set one), or your previous position. I do not believe there is a "step back" in the eclipse debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [Drop To frame](http://help.eclipse.org/indigo/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/debug/ref-droptoframe.htm).

It's on the main toolbar, on the left of other debugging commands.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one way I know that can lead you to that effect. It requires modificatoin of source code, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1; //<-- break point here
    int d = 1;
}
```

set a break point, while debugger stops at that line, change source code of this `main` method to any thing else, e.g.:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 1;
    int b = 1;
    int c = 1; //<-- break point here
    int d = 1;
    int e = 1; //<-- any modification will do
}
```

Now, when press "next" you can choose to let debugger restart.

Other than this work-around, I don't think you can do it in Eclipse.