# How to use *Hot Code Replacement* to correct my xpath of it is incorrect

Tags: java, debugging, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using *Selenium*, *Java* and *Eclipse Mars* to write a test. I decided to use *Hot Code Replacement* to debug my selenium tests. The main reason that I decided to use HCR was to get to my locators (for example: `WebElement searchBox = driverChrome.findElement(By.xpath("bla bla"));`) and try the xpath to see if it works or not, and if not I change it, save it and try it again without running the whole test.

I have this problem that when I change something and click on save it shows:

[image]:

Below find my sample code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "Chrome Drivers\\chromedriverWindows32");
        try {
            WebDriver driverChrome = new ChromeDriver();
            driverChrome.get("http://www.google.com/xhtml");
            driverChrome.manage().window().maximize();
            String name = "bla bla";
            driverChrome.findElement(By.name(name)).click();
            Thread.sleep(2000); // Let the user actually see something!
            driverChrome.quit();
        } catch (Exception e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate :- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23156405/change-execution-of-java-program-while-debugging

Answer (score 0):

**Updated with more detail**

Hot code replacement won't work for every code situation. Consider setting the XPath as a string variable, then modify the value of that variable as part of your debugging.

For example:

```
@Test
public void changeExpression() throws Exception {
    WebDriver browser = new FirefoxDriver();
    browser.get("http://google.com");
    WebElement searchBtn = 
            browser.findElement(By.xpath("*//form//input[@value='Google Search']"));
    //do other stuff...
    browser.quit();
}
```

Now set a breakpoint on the WebElement searchBtn ... statement. Run the test in Debug mode. Step over the breakpoint so the browser.findElement statement executes. You'll either have an initialized WebElement searchBtn or an exception because the xpath was invalid.

Now you can open up the Expressions window in Eclipse (Window -> Show View => Other => Expressions).

You can edit the find statement here, specifically the xpath statement.

[image]

Frankly, if you're just trying to validate Xpaths it would be lots easier to use dev tools in Chrome, IE, or Firefox:

[image]

HTH

Comment: Sorry, I realized I may not have been clear: change the value of the variable by using the Expression window in the debug mode. It's subtly different than hot code update. You can use the Expression window for evaluating/testing find logic, steps, etc.

Comment: But after passing the locator and figuring out that it was wrong, how can I go backward and see if the new value that I assigned to the bannerXpath in Expression window works or not?

Comment: Thanks for you help that is very helpful. my question is: if I found that the xpath was wrong and then I changed it by that Expression window, how can I go back to the breakpoint so the browser.findElement statement executes again?